# Android 9(only observed) using Room(for non-images): Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1

Tags: android, android-room, android-9.0-pie

I've only observed this on Android 9 and possibly only on Samsung devices. I'm storing multiple JSON responses to multiple serialized strings into my DB later to be typeConverted using Moshi again into a model.

The query that causes this error is:

```
@Query(“SELECT * FROM tasks”)
public abstract Flowable<List<TaskEntity>> getAll();
```

The last instance had a total of about 392,000 characters TOTAL in the table. These are actually split up into about 5500 character size entries within the table.

1. Why would the cursor have a problem with ~11k byte sized entries? Does the fact that I'm selecting * mean the cursor is grabbing the whole table into memory and not a single row at a time?
2. Why only Android 9?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the fact that I'm selecting * mean the cursor is grabbing the whole table into memory and not a single row at a time?

`SELECT *` means you are retrieving all columns. A `SELECT` without a `WHERE` clause (or other types of constraints) means that you are retrieving all rows. So, `SELECT * FROM tasks` will attempt to retrieve the entire table contents into memory.

You could add `@Transaction` to this function, as that may help get past this error. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Transaction):

> When used on a `Query` method that has a SELECT statement, the generated code for the `Query` will be run in a transaction. There are 2 main cases where you may want to do that:
>
> - If the result of the query is fairly big, it is better to run it inside a transaction to receive a consistent result. Otherwise, if the query result does not fit into a single `CursorWindow`, the query result may be corrupted due to changes in the database in between cursor window swaps.
> - If the result of the query is a POJO with `Relation` fields, these fields are queried separately. To receive consistent results between these queries, you also want to run them in a single transaction.

Even better would be to not load the entire table's content's into memory (and then convert the entire table's rows into entity objects). Heap space is limited.

> Why only Android 9?

No clue. I wouldn't worry about that — if you focus on retrieving less data, that will have benefits for all your users.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Any insight as to why adding Transaction may help with a cursor overload in a query? Docs just say "...to receive a consistent result". I've used Transaction before to combine a delete with an insert and I believe I understand why that should happen.

Comment: @JimD.: I added some more material about that to the answer.